# How to make a Java program works for any String?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'm just trying to write a java code that make my program works for any string value not only for a specific one.
what I'm trying to do exactly is that I want to make a program like this:

```
public class Q {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String s1 = "Computer";

    String s2 = s1.substring(0,4);
    String s3 = s1.substring(4);

    System.out.println(s3 + s2);

    }

}
```

The result will be :

```
uterComp
```

And my problem is that it works only for this string value (Computer).
I want my code works for any String value.

How to?

Comment: Your program only makes sense for that specific `String` (and maybe not even real "sense" for that one). If you want a more general program, first you have to think about what the general output would be? What is the program *supposed* to do (in human language first)?

Comment: And yet you **still** haven't explained what you want this program to do. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please improve this current question so that the answers will make sense to future visitors.

Comment: Maybe OP is confused about how to pass a command line argument into his program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Q {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2, s3;

        s2 = s1.substring(0, s1.length()/2);
        s3 = s1.substring(s1.length()/2);

        System.out.println(s3+s2);
    }
}
```

Should do the work for words with odd number of characters or even number of characters.

Comment: How do you know that's the desired functionality?

Comment: It is pretty obvious when he asks to do it with other words than "Computer"

Comment: I can imagine a dozen other functionalities that would do the same for the word "Computer", but something completely different for other `Strings`, the simplest one of which would be splitting after the first occurrence of the letter "p" and putting it together the other way round.

Comment: Btw. what's the purpose of your `if`/`else`, if you execute the same code in both cases?

Comment: Thank you for helping me.. it works exactly like what i want

Comment: You're welcome @Ibra

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the lenth of string with length method:

```
int part = s1.length() / 2;
```

then divide your string to 2 parts by using 'part':

```
String s2 = s1.substring(0, div);
String s3 = s1.substring(div);

System.out.println(s3 + s2);
```

Comment: @Ibra you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the string at it's middle then you can try this -

```
int length = s1.length();
String s2 = s1.substring(0,length/2);
String s3 = s1.substring(length/2);

System.out.println(s3 + s2);
```

Comment: yeah this is what I want, but the result is only the first half.

Comment: I tried my string value (Computer) and the result was (Comp) without the rest of it..

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I have fixed it. In the second sub-string `s3` there will be `length/2`

Comment: Thank you it works fine now

Answer (score -1):

The way to do this is create a method that takes a String as a parameter.
Exactly what you did in your main method just do it in a seperate method. Example:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    stringMethod("Computer");//You can insert any String here
}
public static void stringMethod(String s1){
{

    String s2 = s1.substring(0,4);
    String s3 = s1.substring(4);

    System.out.println(s3 + s2);

}
```

This way everytime you want to choose a different String just change the String in the parameters of your method in your main. i.e `stringMethod("Different String");`